# DNS lookup failed on wireless netwok: how to detect what is causing this error?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I have a Windows 7 PC and two mac computers. When using mac comptures, I don't have problems with the wireless home network. When using Windows 7 PC, I cannot get internet access using google chrome until my computer has been on (and logged) in about ten minutes. Chrome says that DNS lookup failed. I have also F-Secure installed on my computer. How can I detect in Windows 7 what is causing this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a reason for this! My router (Cisco EPC3825) has setting in Security tab: block ip flood detection. When I unchecked this option, everything works fine!